# Can't connect to Node.js inspector on exposed Docker container port

Tags: node.js, docker, google-chrome-devtools

Running the command `docker run -p 9222:9229 --name node-inspect-test -d node:alpine node --inspect-brk -e 'console.log("hello world")'` should expose the [node.js inspector](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) on port `9222` on the Docker host.

Running `curl http://localhost:9222/json` results in `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

Requesting the same endpoint from within the container with `docker exec -it node-inspect-test wget -qO- http://localhost:9229/json` succeeds.

Why does the exposed port `9222` not get forwarded to the internal port `9229` successfully?

I'm running Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87 on Ubuntu 16.04.2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default node inspector listens on the loopback interface. The `--inspect-brk` flag has the option of specifying host and port. In order to have the debugger listen on all interfaces so that it is accessible via the Docker host, use the flag `--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229`.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post the answer, sorted my issue out!